Is smoothness preserved under an isometric isomorphism?
Let $(X, \|.\|_1)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $(X, \|.\|_2)$ and $\|.\|_2\leq \|.\|_1$. Assume that $x_0$ is a smooth point of $(X, \|.\|_1)$ and $\|x_0\|_2=1$. According to the definition of a smooth point let the collection of support functionals at $x_0$ be
$$J(x_0)=\{\mu x_1^*:|\mu|=1\},\qquad x_1^*\in (X^*, \|.\|_1^*)\quad \text{and}\quad \|x_1^*\|=1.$$
$\textbf{Definition of Smooth Point:}$ A norm one element $x_0$ is called smooth if the set
$$J(x_0)=\{x^*\in X^*:\|x^*\|=1,x^*(x_0)=1\}$$ is singleton.
My question: Is $x_0$ also smooth in $(X, \|.\|_2)?$ Is the comparison between two norms necessary to conclude this?
I haven't been able to proceed. Please help. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Are the spaces only normed or are they Banach? The notion of smoothness is also not something every functional analyst is used to, so you might want to give a definition in teh body of the question itself: I'm guessing from your statement that a smooth point is a point $x$ at which the set $J(x) = {\Lambda \in X^* \mid |\Lambda|\ = 1 = |\Lambda(x)|}$ is of the form you described?

@BrunoB Thank you for pointing out the thing. Now, I have added the definition in my question.

Do we have $|x_0|_1 = |x_0|_2 = 1$, or only $|x_0|_2 = 1$?

We should have $|x_0|_1=|x_0|_2=1$.

I'll assume for this answer that $\|x_0\|_2 = \|x_0\|_1 = 1$.
Let $\Lambda \in (X, \|\cdot\|_2)^*$ be a support functional for $x_0$ in $(X,\|\cdot\|_2)$, i.e. a functional such that: $$\Lambda(x_0) = \|\Lambda\|_2 = \|x_0\|_2 = 1$$
Then, we have:
$$\forall x \in X,\quad |\Lambda(x)| \leq \|\Lambda\|_2 \|x\|_2 \leq \|\Lambda\|_2 \|x\|_1$$
so that $\Lambda \in (X, \|\cdot\|_1)^*$ with:
$$\|\Lambda\|_1 \leq \|\Lambda\|_2 = 1$$
yet $\Lambda(x_0) = 1 = \|x_0\|_1$ thus implies that: $$\|\Lambda\|_1 = 1 = \Lambda(x_0)$$
Therefore $\Lambda$ is a support functional for $x_0$ in $(X, \|\cdot\|_1)$, and $x_0$ is a smooth point in $(X, \|\cdot\|_2)$ if it was a smooth point in $(X, \|\cdot\|_1)$.

I have understood your answer. But according to the question if we cannot assume $|x_0|_2=1$ can we not able to conclude it from our given hypothesis?

@Tuh This reasoning only works if $|x_0|_2 = |x_0|_1$, otherwise there's a discrepancy in the proof when it comes to finding the norm $|\Lambda|_1$, since the upper and lower bounds for said norm we'll get will be different. Of course it doesn't have to be $1$ but with eveything being $1$ it's easier to write, plus it's what you assumed at the start anyway.

Thank you for your answer. Many thanks
